# Comparing roof life of two different population of homes

Tags: failure-rate

I am trying to compare the initial roof life of two different data sets of homes.  I want to know if the data can be said to show a statistical difference in roof life.
I have two populations.  One has 143 roofs and the other has 477.  The number and age at which roofs were replaced by year of age is shown below.

```
    N1 and Lipizzan combined            Rest of SR      
Age (Yrs)   Repl    Total   % Repl  Repl    Total   % Repl
16    7      7      100%             1       35     3%
15    5     20       25%            10       57    18%
14   11     21       52%            10       38    26%
13    8     15       53%             6       47    13%
12    0      5        0%             1       45     2%
11    0      7        0%             4       40    10%
10    1     21        5%             2       38     5%
9     0     47        0%             3      177     2%
Tot  32    143       22%            37      477     8%
```

The percent replaced seems different, but the smaller sample size of the first data set may add uncertainty.  So I scaled the larger data set by each year to match the smaller data set, keeping the failure rate percent constant.  I also looked at the surviving roofs rather than the failures, hoping that the weighted mean may be different. That results in the data set below.

```
Number of Roofs **Not Replaced**            
Age of Roof   Rest of SR    N1/LIP  Sample Size
9              46.2         47        47
10             19.9         20        21
11              6.3          7         7
12              4.9          5         5
13             13.1          7        15
14             15.5         10        21
15             16.5         15        20
16              6.8          0         7
Total         129.1        111       143
```

Our hypotheses is that the "N1/LIP" population has been replacing roofs earlier than necessary compared to the control group of "Rest of SR".  The weighted mean (age x number of roofs) of the Rest of SR is 10.4 and the N1/Lip is 8.5, so the data would suggest a 1.9 year difference? I would like to be able to state with 95% confidence that they are statistically different.  I am afraid I can't come up with the correct statistical test.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CV, JMS.  I have formatted your tables to make them readable, but find that the headers and titles are cryptic.  It would help to explain what they mean and to give a brief description of how these data were selected.

Comment: As some roofs aren't replaced, your analysis needs to take those lower limits to replacement time into account. Technically, those are right-censored replacement times. That's usually handled by some form of survival analysis.

Comment: The table shows the population of roofs of one neighborhood (N1/LIP) versus a different section of the neighborhood (Rest of SR).  Because they are of different build dates, they are from ages 9 to 16 years.  The number of roofs replaced will increase as the age gets higher.  Theoretically, if weather, siting,, workmanship, etc are the same, the roofs of the same age should fail at approximately the same rate.  But for the 16 year old roofs, for example, the N1/LIP population has replaced all 7 of their roofs while the Rest of SR population has replaced only 1 of 35.

Comment: Even accounting for the small population of 7 for the 16 year old roofs, this seems like it would be statistically different.  The same can be said for 13 and perhaps 14 year old roofs, while the 15 year old roofs are almost statistically the same (25 vs 18% replacement rate.)  I guess I can statistically compare the two populations by each year and the summarize, but I was hoping to compare the entire population by roof life or per cent replaced to show a difference.